# Query showing a result like 0 when the site is down or not responding

Tags: scripting, qlikview

I have the following query loaded in Qlikview that returns results from a website (works fine) but I want to display a result when, for example, the site is down or not responding (something like else or if null).

```
LOAD
Server  as JDBCDSMonitorServer, 
Runtime  as JDBCDSMonitorRuntime, 
Failures  as JDBCDSMonitorFailures,
Waiting  as JDBCDSMonitorWaiting,
State  as JDBCDSMonitorState
FROM
"http://url"
(html, codepage is 1252, embedded labels)
;
```

How should I have the query showing a result like 0 when the site is down or not responding? Many thanks for the help!

Comment: In this case I'm using Qlikview to fetch data from a url site. It loads the columns from the url and then prompts the results.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the heads up, I just changed subject and tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I just need to add in the code the following:

I added the following in the initial code and it works.

SET ErrorMode = '0';